# Delete push message (Firebase) from device (Android and IOS) if already shown

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Have written service, witch sends push messages on IOS and Android devices and delete messages(after 1 hour), if device is switched off. But i need also to delete messages, if its already shown on device (in case, when user, for example, haven`t unlocked device for a long time and to prevent showing too many messages). How i build push message:

```
Notification notify = Notification.builder()
        .setTitle(folder.getName())
        .setBody("Открыть поступивший документ")
        .build();
Message msg = Message.builder()
        .setToken(device.getDevice_id())
        .setNotification(notify)
        .putData("folderOid", folder.name())
        .putData("documentOid", documentOid)
        .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                .setTtl(3600000)
                .build())
        /* настройки для ios */
        .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder()
                .putHeader("apns-priority", "5")
                .putHeader("apns-expiration", "3600000")
                .setAps(Aps.builder()
                        .setMutableContent(true)
                        .setBadge(1)
                        .build())
                .build())
        .build();
```

I expect the messages to be deleted from device by time out of 1 hour.
I've tried to add `tag` or/and `collapse-key` in `setNotification(Android Notification.builder()`, but it works not the way i need: it removes previous message, when the newer is sent and i need to remove all sent messages from device by timeout.

As i've read here https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/remove-notifications-and-ttl there is no other way to remove(not replacing) notification without using for Android: `Service Extension` from Android API or `setting Badge Count to 0`, for IOS: Apple native `removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:) method and getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler:) method` to target the expired notifications and remove them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @Alex Mamo This code works well. Its just an example how im sending notifications and here i want to implement functionality of deleting messages from device by timeout.

Comment: The description of your question is vague. Please state what exactly is the problem you are facing and what you have tried

Comment: @Noah I've tried to add `tag` or/and `collapse-key` in `setNotification(Android Notification.builder()`, but it works not the way i need: it removes previous message, when the newer is sent and i need to remove all sent messages from device by timeout.

Comment: Now, edit your question with more detail so that people can help you

Comment: @Noah Witch details do you need? I really don't uderstand.. I wrote detailed question with code and what i've tried to solve this problem.. I will be glad to add more info, but tell me please, what else do you need? I need to delete push messages from device from server side by timeout, like `collapse_id` do (as i wrote before), but not replacing message with another, i need just delete all messages if time comes.

Comment: @ViktorKondratsiuk, I can't solve the problem because the code should only include a well-formatted code, of only the parts that is giving you issue, remove the rest